# Red Hat support for Docker

Tags: docker, redhat

We are currently running Red Hat 5. But I saw documentation that says docker is only supported on Red Hat 7. So we have to upgrade to Red Hat 7 or we can't use docker at all on RHEL 5?  Alternatively we can consider to switch to Ubuntu.

How do others solve the similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to upgrade from RHEL5 to use Docker.

The official Docker release deprecated RHEL6 support from 1.7 ([and inadvertently broke it in 1.7.0 but fixed in 1.7.1](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14365)). Support for RHEL6 was dropped in Docker 1.8.  Since then, a RHEL7 based distro with a 3.10+ kernel has been required.

There is a docker-io-1.7.1-2 package available on [EPEL](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/) for RHEL6.5+ based distros.  RHEL6 runs an older 2.6 kernel with back ported fixes so docker can work. This kernel must be at `2.6.32-431` or higher.

RHEL doesn't support AUFS which is the most commonly used Docker [storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/). By default RHEL uses a loopback storage driver which is [not production ready](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/notes-on-fedora-centos-and-docker-storage-drivers/). The EPEL packages provide `docker-storage-setup` to setup thin provisioned LVM. You need to do this setup manually if you want to run the docker.com packages.

Personally I would recommend going with a [recent debian](https://www.debian.org/News/2016/20160402) based distribution running the [official docker packages](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/linux/step_one/) for timely updates.  If you are on EC2, Amazons AMI will do nicely though.

Comment: How is debian compared to ubuntu for support? Is it still true that debian has only community support and no commercial support?

Comment: Yeah, the Debian project doesn't have a parent company like Canonical who provides an official support service.  16.04.1 LTS should be available in a month or two if you need Canonical support.